# High-availability for ZMQ traffic

Tags: high-availability

We have a lot of incoming third-party ZMQ traffic (`zmq.PULL` on our side).

We need to implement a high-availability solution for that traffic. At the very least, we need to be able to manually switch the actual data receiver machine to another one without losing (much) traffic.

Please advise an existing high-availability solution that supports ZMQ. (Yes, it will not be hard to code one, but we'd like to use something already well-tested and proven, just to be on the safe side.)

Comment: I'm wondering, will HAProxy in tcp mode work? Probably not, due to multi-part ZMQ messages (which ought all go to the same machine)... Is there a way to teach HAProxy that?

Comment: Hi, did you come up with something at the end?

Comment: Nope. Convinced the third party to drop the ZMQ instead.

Comment: I guess that's an option too. :) What did you end up with instead?

Comment: AFAIR, the nanomsg.